# Do CSS combinators add specificity to a CSS selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

The [mdn article about CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Selector_Types) states:

> Universal selector (*), combinators (+, >, ~, ' ') and negation pseudo-class (:not()) have no effect on specificity. (The selectors declared inside :not() do, however.)

However my experience is that combinators do have an effect, see this example:

```css
div > p {
  color: red;
}

p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>First Paragraph</p>
  <p>Second Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

So the above quote claims, that CSS combinators have no effect on specificity. If that quote is right, how is it meant then, as my code example shows the opposite?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity

Comment: could be except they never mention the combinators AFAIK therefore this dupe wouldn't cover this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your snippet is that you have two selectors(`div > p`) in the 1st rule and in the 2nd rule only one selector(`p`), therefore the 1st rule is more specific, so the article is correct.

See the snippet below using the same 2 selectors, but the 1st having a combinator `>`, as they have the same specificity the latter will apply due to cascading.

```css
div > p {
  color: red;
}

div p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>First Paragraph</p>
  <p>Second Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

You can see the specificity for `div p`, `div > p` and `p` below

[image: SS]

Comment: Assuming "CSS selector" and "CSS rule" being the exact same, your answer might bring some confusion. However, knowing that the specificity of above rule/selector is actually defined by counting the amount of "simple selectors", helped a lot to understand. So the combinators are just not counted to the specificity declaring number. Your answer gave the crucial hint which lead me to the helpful W3C page: https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/#specificity

Comment: CSS rule is different than the CSS selector.. a css selector is what you choose to style.. The CSS rule is what you style (including the selector) -selector and properties

Comment: Also see [why combinators don't add specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096829/why-do-foo-bar-and-foo-bar-have-the-same-specificity-in-css).